# Reading from a text file and recursively merge sorting it

Tags: java, filereader, mergesort

I know this question seems to be a duplicate but I have looked at every related question over and over again and couldn't find the answer to my question. I am supposed to read from a text file whose name is determined from a user input. The file contains a unsorted set of type double numbers, such as:

"0.1212312"
"0.0013315"
"0.0106026"

I am then prompted to merge sort it through recursive means. My program has no problem as far as compiling goes, and I don't get any run-time errors, however the program does not respond correctly to certain inputs and I can't seem to figure out why. So I ask for my senpais' assitance. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class ProjectAssingment3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter file name please:");
        Scanner input;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String in;
        in = input.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
        {
            if(Character.isWhitespace(in.charAt(i)))count++;
        }
        while(in.equals(null)||(count>1))
        {
            count=0;
            for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) // Counts the white spaces to determine the number of arguments in input
            {
                if(Character.isWhitespace(in.charAt(i)))
            count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Please try again!");
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            in = input.nextLine();
        }
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(in)));
            List<Double> lines = new ArrayList<Double>();
            int i =0;
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
            {
            if(sc.nextLine().equals(null))//Checks if any empty lines
            {
                System.out.println("Empty Line Encountered!");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            else if(!sc.hasNextDouble())//Checks if any non-double type lines
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Line Encountered" + sc.nextLine());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            lines.add(Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine()));
            System.out.println(lines.get(i));i++; //Prints out original Unsorted array.
        }
        sc.close();

        //Unboxes the values from the ArrayList onto a array of type double
        double arr[] = new double[lines.size()];
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            arr[j] = lines.get(j);
        }
        mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);

        //Prints the sorted array
        for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[x]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("Failed to read input file:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public static void doMerge(double [] numbers, int left, int mid, int right)
{
  double [] temp = new double[25];
  int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;  
  left_end = (mid - 1);
  tmp_pos = left;
  num_elements = (right - left + 1);
  while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
  {
        if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])
          temp[tmp_pos] = numbers[left++];
        else
          temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
        }
        while (left <= left_end)
          temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
        while (mid <= right)
          temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
        for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
        {
          numbers[right] = temp[right];
          right--;
        }
    }
    public static void mergeSort(double [] numbers, int left, int right)
    {
    int mid;
    if (right > left)
    {
      mid = (right + left) / 2;
      mergeSort(numbers, left, mid);
      mergeSort(numbers, (mid + 1), right);
      doMerge(numbers, left, (mid+1), right);
    }
}
```

}

And yes, this is indeed an assignment given to me, however I'm honestly not asking for any of you guys to just do it for me. I am genuinely stomped and merely asking for some clarification!

I appreciate any effort put into this silly question of mine!

Comment: Did you try printing out to check where actually it s not working properly?

Comment: Yes I had print lines all over it, but I deleted before posting it here as I thought it make it messy.. It seems to recognize invalid file names but whenever I type the actual name of the file it just doesn't respond

Comment: Then it seems you have problems with either `/`,`\` or `whitespace`. Does your file name have any space?

Comment: The user input cannot have more than one argument, thats why I'm checking the white spaces. My file name is "input-10.txt", but whenever I type the file name,  it does not it give me a directory not found error, it just doesn't execute the rest of the code

Comment: If you used a relative path, then perhaps program's current working directory is not what you think it is. Try printing that (google for how), and then explicitly test if the input file exists (google for how).

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code using an IDE? Put a breakpoing on the entry of main method, and move step by step, and each step monitor the variables to see whether it is the expected results.

Comment: you should give exact directory like `C:/users/username/etc/input-10.txt`

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thank you! If I didn't have restrictions on the assignment I would've just given it an exact directory as suggested, however I can't expect the user to input the exact file directory.

Comment: @MJSG I am writing this code using BlueJ and yes I have tried using the debugger utility and I got nothing from it.

Answer (score 0):

When I give full path it accepts the file but gives another exception.

Also you throw exception but who is catching it?

One last thing, the syntax of main is `public static void main(String[] args)`, it **MUST** get `String[]args` as parameter, (at least in eclipse), otherwise it wont recognize the main method

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem doesn't seem to be with the path directory, as the program is able to find the file with no problem. And also, could you elaborate on your question a little more please. I'm not very familiar with try and catch, so I could really use some clarification. Thank you

Comment: When you throw some exception, some other method should catch it, so there s no point of throwing exception in main

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have a catch declaration in my code but I'll double check that. Thank you

Comment: Doesnt it give any error when you type correct directory?

Comment: I just checked it and yes it does. But I find it weird because I have made sure over and over again that the file name I am inputing is the correct one, so I don't understand why it would give me an error with exact directory and not with a relative one

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort you put into this man. I will try to figure it out, it's probably going to be something incredibly silly but yeah thanks a bunch.

Comment: Relative directory hard to deal with sometimes. U might have different problems. Also, ur code cant compile without 'String [] args' as parameter

Comment: Yeah I fixed that although it works just fine without it, but thanks. And I agree, I would much rather work with exact ones than relatives.. It's just that my professor wanted it that way so it couldn't be helped.